# Enforce relationship match in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker, referential-integrity

I have two FileMaker tables that are linked using a relationship. The relationships matches based on the content of two fields:

```
TableA.Foo matches TableB.Foo
TableA.Bar matches TableB.Bar
```

Is there a way to enforce constraints on this relationship in FileMaker? When entering objects in `TableA`, I'd like to ensure that the values entered in fields `Foo` and `Bar` are such that there exists a corresponding record in `TableB`. Is this possible?

Bonus points if I could somehow autocomplete values of `Bar` based on the entries of `TableB` and the value already entered in `Foo`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "enforce constraints"? Please do not use such an abstract example. Give your tables meaningful names (at minimum, use Parent and Child to describe a generic relationship).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question *as asked*:

1. You can validate the `Bar` field (or any other field) by
   calculation:

   ```
   not IsEmpty ( TableB::Foo )
   ```

   Set the validation to validate `Always`. This will throw a
   validation error if you try to commit a record in TableA without
   having a related record in TableB.
2. To auto-complete based on values in another field, you must format
   the target field as Drop-down list with Auto-complete using a value
   list.

   Before defining the value list, set up a new relationship (using a
   new occurrence of TableB) as:

   ```
       TableA::Foo = TableB 2::Foo
   ```

   Then define the value list to use values from TableB 2::Bar, show only related values starting from TableA.

I suspect there may be better ways to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Thanks! This indeed answers the question.

Regarding point 2, I've found a detailed description here: https://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/non_toc.43.23.html